# Making two physical servers available via one Internet connection on different domains

Tags: networking, router, domain

I’m setting up a Solidworks Vault server (using [these](http://help.solidworks.com/2014/English/PDMWorks/t_Port_Conflicts_TroubleVault_WPDM.htm) ports) for a *first* robotics team I’m on.

The building we’re in has a decent Internet connection, but it’s only a *single* connection.

There are other teams which share the building, who would also like to use Solidworks Vault on separate hardware.

Our problem is making all the teams’ servers available on the Internet, through the same connection at the same time, on *different*, team-specific, domains.

We’ll be using Windows 10 Enterprise Edition on our server, for what it’s worth.

Also, I believe that our modem is separate from our router.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Multiple boxes - or computers. It's a fairly common term in Linux stuff.

Comment: When you say domain, I presume you mean hostnames/fqdns? Why can't you have a single box (terminal server) with which they remote to, and then access their hardware internally? Or use a VPN to get to the internal and then access the services directly?

Comment: @prateek61: Good idea! We could do that, that actually might work better.